# Setting the appearence of a SVG element

Tags: jquery, svg

Using SVG, how can I set the appearence of the svg element to be the table that it contains?
The element I'm trying to change is below:

```
<rect style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    fill-opacity: 0.784884; 
    stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    stroke-width: 0.447214; 
    stroke-miterlimit: 1; stroke-opacity: 0.784884; 
    stroke-dasharray: none;" 
    id="R4" width="600" height="80" x="70" y="322.36218" class="wz-rack" inkscape:label="">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 94.4444%;">
             <img href="../smoothness/images/greenBackground.png"/>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 5.55556%;">
             <img href="../smoothness/images/redBackground.png"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</rect>
```

So basically, what I was trying to do was inserting a table with 2 tds using 2 different pictures with a set width percentage to make my svg element have 2 colors but the SVG's color remains the same.

EDIT:

What I've tried but didn't work:

```
 $('rect[class^="wz-rack"]').each(function() {
            var partialId = $(this).attr('id');
            var gradient = "<linearGradient id='red_green_-*-' x1='0%' y1='0%' x2='100%' y2='0%'>".replace("-*-", partialId);
            gradient += "<stop offset='0%' style='stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:0.784884'/>";
            gradient += "<stop offset='94.4444%' style='stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:0.784884'/>";
            gradient += "<stop offset='94.4444%' style='stop-color:rgb(0,255,0); stop-opacity:0.784884'/>";
            gradient += "<stop offset='100%' style='stop-color:rgb(0,255,0); stop-opacity:0.784884'/>";
            gradient += "</linearGradient>";
            $('#defs4').append(gradient);
            var id = "#red_green_p".replace("p", partialId);

            $(this).attr('fill', id);

        });

        $('rect[class^="wz-rack"]').each(function() {

            var zoneId = $(this).attr('id');
            var WarehouseId = $('#WarehouseId').val();

            var thisRack = $(this);

            var url = '<%= Url.Action("GetRackBusyPercent", "Warehouses", new {zoneId="-x-", warehouseId = "-y-"}) %>'.replace("-x-", zoneId).replace("-y-", WarehouseId)
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: url,
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    var percentArray = JSON.parse(data);
                    var def = $('#red_green_' + zoneId);

                    var defArray = def.find('stop');

                    defArray[1].setAttribute("offset", percentArray[0] + "%")
                    defArray[2].setAttribute("offset", percentArray[0] + "%")


                    //thisRack.attr("fill", "url(#-*-) ; fill-opacity: 0.784884; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0.447214; stroke-miterlimit: 1; stroke-opacity: 0.784884; stroke-dasharray: none;".replace("-*-", def.attr('id')));
                }
            });
```

EDIT 2:

```
$($('rect[class^="wz-rack"]'), svg.root()).each(function() {

            var partialId = $(this).attr('id');
            var gradient = "<linearGradient id='red_green_-*-' x1='0%' y1='0%' x2='100%' y2='0%'>".replace("-*-", partialId);
            gradient += "<stop offset='0%' stop-color='red' />";
            gradient += "<stop offset='94.4444%' stop-color='red' />";
            gradient += "<stop offset='94.4444%' stop-color='green' />";
            gradient += "<stop offset='100%' stop-color='green' />";
            gradient += "</linearGradient>";

            $('#defs4').append(gradient);
            var id = "#red_green_p".replace("p", partialId);


            $(this).removeAttr('style');
            $(this).attr('fill', "url(#red_green_K)".replace("K", partialId));
            $(this).attr('fill-opacity', '0.784884');
            $(this).attr('stroke', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
            $(this).attr('stroke-width', '0.447214');
            $(this).attr('stroke-miterlimit', '1');
            $(this).attr('stroke-opacity', '0.784884');
            $(this).attr('stroke-dasharray', 'none');



        });
```

My 2nd attempt at getting some colour on my svg rects, but not even this has worked...

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use SVG here? It seems that HTML will actually be more appropriate with respect to what your code sample is attempting to achieve. But this may simply be because you oversimplifed your example. If that's the case, please revise your question with a more representative example.

Comment: Well, SVG is being used here because of other reasons so I really must stick to SVG. I had a look at SVG gradient but had no idea how I'd color its surfance with a color on the left and another on the right just by using %. That's all I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your gradient like this:

```
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="red_green_94" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:0.784884"/>
        <stop offset="94.4444%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:0.784884"/>
        <stop offset="94.4444%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0); stop-opacity:0.784884"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0); stop-opacity:0.784884"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

The key point is that for blocks of solid colour you have to set a stop at either end of the block.  So there's a stop at the start of the red block, a stop at the end of the red block, then a stop in the same place for the start of the green block before the final stop for the end of the green block.

Then assign the gradient to your rectangle using the id:

```
<rect style="fill: url(#red_green_94); 
    fill-opacity: 0.784884; 
    stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    stroke-width: 0.447214; 
    stroke-miterlimit: 1; stroke-opacity: 0.784884; 
    stroke-dasharray: none;" 
    id="R4" width="600" height="80" x="70" y="322.36218" class="wz-rack" >
</rect>
```

[Here's a working example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/gradient-fill.svg).

--edit

Here's [another example where the gradient is adjusted by JavaScript](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/gradient-fill-1.html), basically grab the `stop` elements and set the `offset` attribute directly.

Comment: Thanks Robertc, that's what I wanted to do. Now, if I wanted to assign the color of my svg rectangle via jQuery dynamically, how should the code work like? I'm asking since I noticed you're placing the gradient inside the defs tag. I will have to change the percentage of my colors dynamically according to a number of settings the user chooses. I'd really appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: @Hallaghan If you want to change the colours dynamically then it ought to be possible to manipulate the style attributes on the stops directly, but that's probably not the best way to do it.  Probably best to use Raphaël which gives you a nice shorthand for creating gradients, or just have two rectangles instead of one and adjust their size.  I'll work out a couple more examples.

Comment: Thanks again Robert. I'll just have to work until tomorrow to try it out on my code. I'm short on access to my work laptop :)

Comment: Robert, it didn't quite work for me. I'll post on my original post what I wrote.

Comment: @Hallaghan jQuery methods won't work properly with an SVG DOM.  Either use JavaScript DOM methods like I did, or try getting sorted out with the jquery.svg extension: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#dom

Comment: If I would use JavaScript DOM methods, how should my code look like? I'm sorry but I'm very inexperienced in javascript. The whole problem is that I need to assign the color dynamically because I'm getting the % of each colour using an ajax call to get the values from the server, as I was asked by my company.

Comment: Well, I am already using the jquery.svg extention. How can I adapt my code to work like shown in the extension page?

Comment: @Hallaghan Have you looked at the code in my second example?  I've not used jquery.svg myself so I can't be much help with that, from my experience the hardest bit is getting a reference to the actual SVG document.

Comment: I can't select your svg canvas with firebug, from your second example, so there are many things I can't see.

Comment: @Hallaghan There's no code in the SVG; the SVG in the second example is the file from the first example.  All the code will be visible if you right click on the page and do view source.

Comment: It is loading the object like this: <rect style="" id="R4" width="600" height="80" x="70" y="322.36218" class="wz-rack" inkscape:label="" fill="url(#red_green_R4)" fill-opacity="0.784884" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="0.447214" stroke-miterlimit="1" stroke-opacity="0.784884" stroke-dasharray="none"/>
But I still get no color...

Comment: The gradient rendered like this: <lineargradient y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="red_green_R4"><stop stop-color="red" offset="0%"></stop><stop stop-color="red" offset="94.4444%"></stop><stop stop-color="green" offset="94.4444%"></stop><stop stop-color="green" offset="100%"></stop></lineargradient>

Comment: @Hallagan You need to load the gradient object and adjust that, the rectangle will update automatically.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you meant by loading the gradient object and adjust it...

Comment: @Hallagan Sorry, 'loading' could mean several different things.  In this context I mean you're loading DOM objects into variables and then adjusting those objects; load the gradient object into a variable and then adjust the attributes of it's <stop> in the same way I did in my second example.

Comment: Yes, I have done that to adjust the stops. But the problem is that, even before adjusting, my svg rect never has any color on it after loading the linearGradient.

Comment: @Hallagan From looking at your code I would say this: `$(this).attr('fill', id);` needs to be more like `$(this).attr('fill', 'url(' + id + ')');`  If it's anything more complex than that you'll have to wait until I get home from work and can look at it in more detail.

Comment: Well, I was doing it like this: $(this).attr('fill', "url(#red_green_K)".replace("K", partialId))
Where partialId is the id of the corresponding gradient. It never changed colour although the code rendered correctly.

Comment: @Hallagan I've had another look at your code but I don't think there's much more help I can offer.  Your code is considerably more complex than my example despite trying to achieve broadly the same thing, the main difference being where you're getting the new percentage value from.  It seems like you're struggling to debug you're own code too, so maybe you should consider simplifying to the bare bones just to get it working.  Is there any reason why you can't just create a set of 100 gradients in a separate file and just update which one is used for the fill?

Comment: I had previously tried to make the code fairly simpler just to get to see some color on my svgs to detect where the problem could be coming from but with no results. Check my EDIT 2.

Comment: @Hallagan Yes, as I mentioned, you seem to be struggling to debug your own code, and I can't debug your code from the snippets of it you're posting, because if I copy and paste that into an editor it won't do anything.  The problem you originally had, of adjusting the gradient dynamically, is solved in my example.  The problem you are currently having could be just about anything.

Comment: @Robert, I'm closing this question and I awarded you with the correct answer because you did answer my question, even if I still have problems. The rest of it, I will fix later when I have free time. Thanks Robert.

Comment: @Hallaghan Thanks.  If you can get a simple test case together that exhibits your problem (that others could then replicate from the information in the question) then please consider posting another question.  After a few days to reflect on this, I think you may be approaching the whole problem in the wrong way, but we got sucked into this side issue about the gradients instead of addressing that.